# how to simplify this multiple-CTE solution to this sql question?

Tags: sql, postgresql

DDL:

```
create table transactions 
(
    product_id int,
    store_id int,
    quantity int,
    price numeric
);
```

DML:

```
insert into transactions values
(1, 1, 10, 2),
(2, 1, 5, 2),
(1, 2, 5, 4),
(2, 2, 2, 4),
(2, 3, 1, 20),
(1, 3, 1, 8),
(2, 4, 2, 10),
(1, 5, 2, 5),
(2, 5, 1, 3),
(2, 6, 4, 8);
```

I'm trying to find the top 3 products of the top 3 stores, both are based on sale amount. The solution I have is to use cte as below:

```
with cte as 
(
    select store_id, rank_store 
    from
        (select 
             *,
             dense_rank() over(order by sale desc) as rank_store
         from 
             (select 
                  store_id, sum(quantity * price) as sale 
              from transactions 
              group by 1) t) t2
    where 
        rank_store <= 3
),
cte2 as 
(
    select 
        a.store_id, a.product_id, 
        sum(a.quantity * a.price) as sale_store_product
    from 
        transactions as a 
    join 
        cte as b on a.store_id = b.store_id
    group by 
        1, 2
    order by 
        1, 2
),
cte3 as 
(
    select 
        *,
        dense_rank() over (partition by store_id order by sale_store_product desc) as rank_product
    from 
        cte2
)
select * 
from cte3 
where rank_product <= 3;
```

Here is the expected result:

[image]

Basically, the first cte is to get the top 3 stores based on sale amount, I use `dense_rank()` window function to handle tie cases. then the 2nd cte is to get the top 3 stores' products and their total sale amount. The last cte is to use `dense_rank()` window function again to rank the products in each stores based on their sale amount. then my last query is to get the top 3 products in each store based on the sale amount.

I'm wondering if this can be improved a bit since I feel three CTEs is kind of too complicated. Appreciate for sharing any solutions and ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find the top 3 products of the top 3 stores

How can this be done without aggregating the data twice -- once for store/products and once for stores?  This is possible using window functions along with aggregation:

```
select sp.*
from (select sp.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by store_sales, store_id) as store_seqnum
      from (select t.store_id, t.product_id,
                   sum(quantity * price) as sp_sales,
                   sum(sum(quantity * price)) over (partition by store_id) as store_sales,
                   row_number() over (partition by t.store_id order by sum(quantity * price)) as sp_seqnum
            from transactions t
            group by t.store_id, t.product_id
           ) sp
      ) sp
where store_seqnum <= 3 and sp_seqnum <= 3;
```

The inner subquery calculates the product/store information.  The next level ranks the stores -- notes that ties are broken using `store_id`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dec3ce9bbbb52a587a58a75c798a1f67) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Looks like this can't get the expected answer.

Comment: @JamesWang . . . Your question specifies:  "'I'm trying to find the top 3 products of the top 3 stores,"  The results in your question have *four* stores.  Something is off.  This answers the question that you *asked*.

Comment: ...there are multiple stores, and we need to find the top 3 stores which have the best sales, and then for these top 3 stores, find the top three products based on the sales. Hopefully this clarify this a bit.